# How to retrieve phone numbers in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I followed the tutorial given on the developers.android.com and I was successfully able to retrieve all the names of the people using the ContactsContract class. 
But my requirement is to retrieve all the names of the people based on phone numbers.

My ContactsQuery.java is as follows:

```
@TargetApi (Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public interface ContactsQuery {

final static int QUERY_ID = 1;

final static Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

final static Uri FILTER_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI;

final static String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ? "
        + " AND " +
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

final static String SORT_ORDER = hasHoneycomb () ?
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY :
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;

final static String[] PROJECTION = {
        // The contact's row id
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID ,

        // A pointer to the contact that is guaranteed to be more permanent than _ID. Given
        // a contact's current _ID value and LOOKUP_KEY, the Contacts Provider can generate
        // a "permanent" contact URI.
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY ,

        // In platform version 3.0 and later, the Contacts table contains
        // DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, which either contains the contact's displayable name or
        // some other useful identifier such as an email address. This column isn't
        // available in earlier versions of Android, so you must use Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        // instead.
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME ,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};

final static String[] SELECTION_ARGS = { "7276844531" };

public static final int ID           = 0;
public static final int LOOKUP_KEY   = 1;
public static final int DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
public static final int SORT_KEY     = 3;
}
```

My ContactsFragment.java is as follows:

```
public class ContactsFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

public static ContactsFragment getInstance () {return new ContactsFragment ();}

private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
private Context         mContext;

private String[] users;
private String mSearchTerm = String.valueOf ( getAllUsers () );

public ContactsFragment () {}

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setHasOptionsMenu ( true );
    mContext = getActivity ();
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter ( mContext );
}

private String[] getAllUsers () {

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery ();
    query.whereExists ( "phone" );
    query.setCachePolicy ( ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK );
    query.findInBackground ( new FindCallback<ParseUser> () {
        @Override
        public void done (List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
            if ( parseUsers != null ) {
                users = new String[parseUsers.size ()];
                int index = 0;
                for ( ParseUser user : parseUsers ) {
                    users[index] = String.valueOf ( user );
                    index++;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e ( "ABHIMANYU", e.getMessage () );
            }
        }
    } );
    return users;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false );
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated ( savedInstanceState );

    setListAdapter ( mAdapter );
    getListView ().setOnItemClickListener ( this );
    getLoaderManager ().initLoader ( ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, this );
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader (int id, Bundle bundle) {
    if ( id == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID ) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath ( ContactsQuery.FILTER_URI, Uri.encode ( "7276844531" ) );

        return new CursorLoader (
                mContext,
                contentUri,
                ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
                ContactsQuery.SELECTION,
                ContactsQuery.SELECTION_ARGS,
                ContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER
        );
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished (Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    if ( cursorLoader.getId () == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID ) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor ( cursor );
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset (Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
    if ( cursorLoader.getId () == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID ) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor ( null );
    }
}

@TargetApi (Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor ();
    cursor.moveToPosition ( position );
    String displayName = cursor.getString ( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow ( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    ) );
    final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri (
            cursor.getLong ( ContactsQuery.ID ),
            cursor.getString ( ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY )
    );
    Log.w ( "ABHIMANYU", "Uri: " + uri.toString () );

    Intent intent = new Intent ( mContext, MessagingActivity.class );
    intent.setData ( uri );
    intent.putExtra ( "name", displayName );
    mContext.startActivity ( intent );
}
}
```

I get no result even when I have that particular phone number that I have passes as the selection argument in my phone. Can anyone help me with my problem?